# WP Config for FTP credentials

Tags: plugins, themes, wp-config, ftp

Is there a config in WP that allows you to store your FTP credentials? I'm using the Linux webserver at work to develop and it's really annoying to have to but the credentials in every time I add/remove a plugin/theme. Anonymous access is a no-no, so I hoping that this config exists...

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'ftpext');
define('FTP_BASE', '/path/to/wordpress/');
define('FTP_CONTENT_DIR', '/path/to/wordpress/wp-content/');
define('FTP_PLUGIN_DIR ', '/path/to/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/');
define('FTP_PUBKEY', '/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub');
define('FTP_PRIKEY', '/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa');
define('FTP_USER', 'username');
define('FTP_PASS', 'password');
define('FTP_HOST', 'ftp.example.org');
define('FTP_SSL', false);
```

http://digwp.com/2010/11/ftp-in-wpconfig/